# Baofeng UV-9G keypad functions

Tags: baofeng

I have read the Baofeng manual and most of it seems pretty clear.

However, on the numeric keypad there are labels like "BEEP" "TOT", etc.  I assume they toggle a related setting, but I can't figure out how to make that happen.  When I press a keypad button the radio assumes I am entering a channel number (in MR mode).

So how do I make use of the secondary functions/labels on the keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each menu item has a number, e.g. VOX is menu item number 4. You can access it quickly by pressing <kbd>MENU</kbd> <kbd>4</kbd>. The <kbd>4</kbd> key has VOX printed on it to remind you of this.

This is detailed on page 23 and on pages 34-40. There are menu shortcuts for items beyond the first 10, but those aren't printed on the keys.

Comment: I didn't connect them with the shortcut numbers, but that appears to work.